# Three divs floating inside a container and leaves a big space

Tags: css, html

I have a main container that holds three main div parts, two of them are floating to the right, its the "info" and the "trainings" divs and to the left i have the "main feed" called news.

The problem is that to the left of my training div it leaves a big space and i dont know why.. it would be awesome if you guys could take a look at it and see if you find the problem.

I am using a wamp server right now so you guys can have a look at it online, the address for that is http://simpolarna.sytes.net/

The CSS:

```
 /*The content of the site*/
.container {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    width: 92%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    display: table;
}

.container > .news, .container > .training, .container > .info {
    padding: 10px;
}

.container table td {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

/*The news feed*/
.news {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
}

.news > table{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.6);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    width: 100%;
}

/*Todays training*/
.training {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

.training > table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.6);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    width: 100%;
}

/*The information box*/
.info {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    content: "";
    clear: right;
}

.info > table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.6);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.33) 5%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="training">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><?=$weekday?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$times?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Information V.<?=Date('W');?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nu är den gamla tråkiga hemsidan borta och en    ny samt lättanvändlig sida har 
                    kommit fram, f.o.m nu stängs Lagsidan ner för gått och denna nya sida ska stiga!
                    Nu är den gamla tråkiga hemsidan borta och en ny samt lättanvändlig sida har 
                    kommit fram, f.o.m nu stängs Lagsidan ner för gått och denna nya sida ska stiga!<br/><br/>
                    Nu är den gamla tråkiga hemsidan borta och en ny samt lättanvändlig sida har
                    kommit fram, f.o.m nu stängs Lagsidan ner för gått och denna nya sida ska stiga!</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><h3>Nu ska allt gammalt kastas ut!</h3><img src="images/105.gif" alt=""/></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Nu är den gamla tråkiga hemsidan borta och en ny samt lättanvändlig sida har 
                    kommit fram, f.o.m nu stängs Lagsidan ner för gått och denna nya sida ska stiga!</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><h3>Nu ska allt gammalt kastas ut!</h3><img src="images/123.gif" alt=""/></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Nu är den gamla tråkiga hemsidan borta och en ny samt lättanvändlig sida har 
                    kommit fram, f.o.m nu stängs Lagsidan ner för gått och denna nya sida ska stiga!</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><h3>Nu ska allt gammalt kastas ut!</h3><img src="images/112.gif" alt=""/></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Nu är den gamla tråkiga hemsidan borta och en ny samt lättanvändlig sida har 
                    kommit fram, f.o.m nu stängs Lagsidan ner för gått och denna nya sida ska stiga!
                    <img src="images/113.gif" alt=""/></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

The text that is put in is only the expand and fill out the divs for now.

Comment: Sorry, just looked at your site, you're info block is clearing right, which means that you have cleared your training float so nothing will float left next to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove float form news class

css:

```
.news {
display: inline-block;
width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix would be to move the first .news div to the top.

A better fix would be to put the news divs in a container div, which is floated to the left, and put the training and info div in an other div, which is floated to the right.